# How to eliminate Specific record and get both Null & Not Null records in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with ~1K records. I want to eliminate specific records based on 1 column which having both Null values and Not Null values.

I tried below query but I couldn't able to find the solution Since I'm beginner to SQL's.

```
SELECT ID,Name,Dept,Location from db.sample where name<>'B';
```

By using above query I'm getting Not Null records only. But I want to get other than 'B' records.

Sample Data:

```
    ID  Name    Dept        Location
    1   A       Finance     US
    2   B       Marketing   UK
    3           Transport   China
    4   C       HR          Canada
    5   B       Finance     US
    6           Production  IND
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Dept        Location
1   A       Finance     US
3           Transport   China
4   C       HR          Canada
6           Production  IND
```

Answer (score 0):

`where name <> 'B' or name is null`

NULL always compares to any other value as False, so you have to use the "is null" or "is not null" conditions to handle it explicitly.

Or you can use a function like coalesce() to replace NULL with some other value:

`where coalesce(name, 'X') <> 'B'`